# onActivityResult resultCode

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I've seen this question asked many times but none of the answers fit my scenario.I have an App that used `startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode)` method ,and in the Activity which I jumped ,I have used `setResult(REQUEST_OK)`,but in the `onActivityResult()` ,the resultCode is always 0 ,and the requestCode is narmally,please help me for this ,thanks all.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(sitesWapPageActivity, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("loadType", "SitesWapPageActivity");
sitesWapPageActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.CHECK_LOGIN);
```

Comment: please show us the part of code where you set the result..

Comment: if (userManager.isLogin()) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "登录成功", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    LoginActivity.this.finish();
                }

Comment: this is where I setResult

Comment: please post this as a part of your answer and please post the onActivityResult method too...

Comment: here is I setResult.
if (userManager.isLogin()) { Toast.makeText(mContext, "登录成功", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); setResult(RESULT_OK);     and  this .@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); 
        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode = " + resultCode)}

Comment: please post this as a part of your question, as a comment it is not good readable...

Comment: I recommend to pass the result with an intent like `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);`